# Get laravel relations value as attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, maatwebsite-excel

I have two models, `Portal` and `Tag` and relation `many-to-many` between them with extra database `portal_tag`. All working great and I can access to `portal->tag` without problem.

But my goal is to get this model like "all values from model" and all relations value as one attribute, between commas. Is it possible?

Because I need it inside `PortalsExport` class in this form to use in export into CSV libary.

Now its look like this:

```
Portal::with('tags')
  ->select('url','type','topic','description','prohibited','visits','facebook_url','twitter_url','instagram_url')
  ->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
```

I have no idea how to make `tags.name` same as all other options from `select`.

I am using Laravel9 and PHP8.

Comment: What do you mean _I have no idea how to make tags.name same as all other options from select_? Can you provide an example of what you're currently seeing and what you want to see.

Comment: @Peppermintology now it returns model with 9 attributes and one relation with tags. So I can access $portal[0]->url for example. But I need to access same to all tags ID or name to make it export into one column inside CSV file. I mean it have to be exacly as attributes because other way libary will not export it correctly to csv.

Comment: do you want to access tags something like that `$portal[0]->tags_as_string` it's result will be comma separated withing the model i.e. `tags_as_string= "tag-1, tag-2, tag-3"` etc. Am I right?

Comment: @khawAli yes, exacly.

Comment: ok great, I have a solution let me write a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `tags` relations as comma separated string then One approach is, You will need to define a `accessor` in your `Portal` model which will append you `tags array` into `string`. like once I was did in one of my project:

##### Step 1:

```
public function getTagsAsStringAttribute(): string
    {
        $array = $this->tags->pluck('name')->all();

        return implode(", ",
            array_map(function ($k, $v) {
                return $k;
            }, array_keys($array), array_values($array))
        );
    }
```

> In above closure functions, plz verify yourself that you `tag name` value is available in `$k or $v` variable.

##### Step 2:

add that `accessor` in `Portal` model `append` array like that:

```
 protected $appends = [      
        'tags_as_string',
    ];
```

##### Step 3:

In the result of yours below query you will get `tags_as_string` attribute which contains comma separated tags as string.

```
Portal::with('tags')
  ->select('url','type','topic','description','prohibited','visits','facebook_url','twitter_url','instagram_url')
  ->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
```

> If `tags_as_string` shown empty then try it above query without `select()` clause.

Comment: Uuuuum, why are you passing `array_values($array)` to `array_map()` if you don't use any of its data in the callback?  Why not simply `implode(', ', array_keys($this->tags->pluck('name')->all()))`?